# Почему первичный ключ ( мой ID ) неправильно считает ?

Tags: sql-server

Должен идти вот так: 0,1,2,3,4,5 ... +n
А не вот так       : 0,2,3,5,6,7 ... +n
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: весьма забавно) может вы удаляли промежуточные записи?

Comment: @tCode Не помню. Сейчас начинаю добавлять после 29, то выводи вот так: 30, 34. Может ли это быть из-за удаления ? Но, по логике даже после удаления должно быть 30,31.

Comment: Как бы он не считал нельзя ожидать безразрывного первичного ключа и от этого ничего зависеть не должно. Следовательно пропуски не должны волновать. И как вы его кстати получаете поле identity или может секвенс (который кешируется и из за этого могут быть пропуски)

Comment: И после удаления записей никто использованные ранее номера заново выдавать не будет

Comment: Если строки явно не удалялись, а "дыры" в диапазоне ID присутствуют, то может быть были попытки вставки в транзакции, которая была в итоге откачена.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Должен идти вот так: 0,1,2,3,4,5

Если это первичный ключ - автоинкремент, то НЕ ДОЛЖЕН. Автоинкремент должен сгенерировать следующее значение, которое будет больше предыдущего сгенерированного. Всё.

Первичный ключ - он вообще не для Вас. Он - для организации связи таблиц и работы подсистемы поддержания целостности и непротиворечивости данных.

Не пытайтесь на ОДНО поле возложить ДВЕ функции. К тому же несвязанные. Ничем хорошим это не закончится.

Если нужно поле с непрерывной нумерацией для пользовательских целей - создайте для этого отдельное поле и заполняйте его программно (триггер, секвенс и пр.).

Answer (score 1):

> При задании ограничения первичного ключа для таблицы компонента
>   Компонент Database Engine гарантирует уникальность данных путем
>   автоматического создания уникального индекса для первичных ключевых
>   столбцов. Этот индекс также обеспечивает быстрый доступ к данным при
>   использовании первичного ключа в запросах. Если ограничение первичного
>   ключа задано более чем для одного столбца, то значения могут
>   дублироваться в пределах одного столбца, но каждое сочетание значений
>   всех столбцов в определении ограничения первичного ключа должно быть
>   уникальным.

Это означает что, нельзя добавить запись запись, удалить, а потом добавить новую запись, чтобы id не изменился, т.е. если мы уже использовали Id = 7, но удалили запись, то при добавлении новой id автоматически будет равен 8 или больше, если следующие за 7 ключи были использованы.

**Обратите внимание:**  Не ожидайте, что все ключи в таблице будут идти по порядку, если из таблицы была удалена хотя бы одна запись. Это всего лишь индексное поле для быстрого доступа

Источник: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms179610.aspx#PKeys)